# CGI via AJAX fails on Firefox from authenticated server?

Tags: ajax, firefox, .htaccess, authentication, cgi

I have a simple page that uses AJAX to POST data to a cgi script which then writs the data to a file. During the development, I hosted the cgi from my personal cgi-bin (no .htaccess):

```
http://home.mydom.com/~raytheonliszt/cgi-bin/txt_input.cgi
```

This worked on Firefox and IE.

When I was done developing, I copied the cgi to the production server (with .htaccess) on the same domain,

```
http://front.mydom.com/prod/cgi-bin/txt_input.cgi
```

On IE, it worked fine, but it failed in Firefox! The cgi was never called. The AJAX got return code 4 immediately and nothing happened, no output file was generated.

Does anyone know what the heck is going on??? Any help would be greatly appreciated (out of options at this point!)

Thanks!